# Check if mouse is over element A OR element B

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to check if the mouse is over one of two elements?

I have this code which will hide my menu:

```
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".chapterMenuContainer", function() {
            //mouse leave
            $('.chapterMenuContainer').stop().animate({
                maxHeight: '0'
            }, 100);
        });
```

I would like to execute the animation only if the mouse is no longer over .chapterMenuContainer OR another class called .chapterMenuHeading. These two classes need to be siblings for structural reasons. Is it possible to check if the mouse is no longer over either one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a comma separated list of selectors to the the event listener. Then use `this` to target the specific element that the mouse "left".

```
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".chapterMenuContainer, .chapterMenuHeading", function() {
  //mouse leave
  $(this).stop().animate({
    maxHeight: '0'
  }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this might be a bit silly, but i would suggest adding a common class between both elements such as `.chapterMenu` and using a event handling function such as `.on("mouseenter mouseleave")` and within that you can use the `hasClass` function within an if/else condition to execute the relevant code, for the respective element classes.